# Show that jordan matrix with k blocks in diagonal has exactly k independent eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

How can I prove that a Jordan matrix with k blocks in the diagonal has exactly k independent eigenvectors.

Can you help me to find a formal proof of this statement?

Comment: Are you convinced that a Jordan block has, up to linear dependence, one eigenvector?